# Is the sentence "George's inviting her should please Mary" correct?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

As far as I know, this sentence should be George's invitation should please Mary. But in an English book, I am recently studying it is stated in that form. Is it grammatically accurate?

Comment: It's fine ***with or without the possessive*** (it's just a matter of whether we treat the "progressive/gerund" ***inviting*** as a noun or a verb, both of which are perfectly acceptable choices in such contexts). Some people might have a strong preference for the *non-possessive* form (perhaps just on the grounds that it's ***simpler***), but it's basically a stylistic choice. So ***George's** inviting her should please Mary* is a perfectly acceptable alternative to ***George** inviting her should please Mary*.

Comment: Yes. Note also that the genitive "George's inviting her ..."  is in competition with the plain form "George inviting her ..", the only difference being that the genitive is more formal.

Comment: @BillJ: On reflection, I realise you're quite right that the possessive is more "formal". So much so that an NGram comparing [***His** coming here is / **Him** coming here is](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=His+coming+here+is%2CHim+coming+here+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHis%20coming%20here%20is%3B%2Cc0) [unwise]* doesn't find enough of the second (non-possessive) version to chart  at all. I actually expected they'd be about equally common, so I guess that's the difference ***being in print*** makes. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.